# python number length validator

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a python script that validates if an input number is the required length,
for example the input number has to be : 1234567890.  The script should check that it is indeed 10 digits long.  I could not find any examples of this.

The checked number is taken from a file.

Answer (score 3):

If it's taken from a file then it's a string.

```
>>> len('1234567890') == 10
True
```

Comment: And this also works in the case where leading zeroes are allowed in order to pad to 10 digits - often the case where the "number" is a bank account ID or similar.  If 0123456789 is an allowed value, then this works where integer maths does not.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using regular expressions:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '1234567890'

In [3]: re.match(r'^\d{10}$', s)
Out[3]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x184f238>

In [4]: re.match(r'^\d{10}$', '99999')
```

The above regex ensures that the string consists of exactly ten decimal digits and nothing else. In this example, `re.match` returns a match object if the check passes or `None` otherwise.

Comment: I probably would have done this myself but I wonder if it would be overkill to use regular expressions for this particularly if we can do this using a combination of `len()` and `isnumeric()`.

Answer (score 1):

Math - if you need the int anyway:

```
10**10 <= int('12334567890') < 10**11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len( str( int( input_variable) ) ) != 10:
     fire_milton(burn_this_place_down=True)
```